# How to expand one row to multiple rows according to its value in Pandas

Tags: pandas

This is a DataFrame I have for example. Please refer the image link.

**Before:**
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaSW1.png)

```
d = {1: ['2134',20, 1,1,1,0], 2: ['1010',5, 1,0,0,0], 3: ['3457',15, 0,1,1,0]}
columns=['Code', 'Price', 'Bacon','Onion','Tomato', 'Cheese'] 

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data=d, orient='index').sort_index()
df.columns = columns
```

What I want to do is expanding a single row into multiple rows. Then the Dataframe should be look like the image of below link. The intention is using some columns(from 'Bacon' to 'Cheese') as categories.

**After:** 
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2wVI.png)

I tried to find the answer, but failed. Thanks.

Comment: But i didn't get any image. I just gave one answer in generic. Please check , it might help.

Comment: It surprises me that there is not more traffic on this question.

Comment: Please add images inside the post using the `![title](url)` notation (mind the exclamation mark)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first reshape with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then filter by [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) from column `level_2` and last [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) columns for add missing with no `1` and [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['Code', 'Price']) \
       .stack() \
       .reset_index(level=2, name='val') \
       .query('val == 1') \
       .level_2.str.get_dummies() \
       .reindex(columns=df.columns[2:], fill_value=0) \
       .reset_index()
print (df)
   Code  Price  Bacon  Onion  Tomato  Cheese
0  2134     20      1      0       0       0
1  2134     20      0      1       0       0
2  2134     20      0      0       1       0
3  1010      5      1      0       0       0
4  3457     15      0      1       0       0
5  3457     15      0      0       1       0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **stack** and transpose to do this operation and format accordingly.

```
df = df.stack().to_frame().T
df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(*c) for c in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.melt` to put all the food in one column and then `pd.get_dummies` to expand the columns.

```
df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Code', 'Price'])
df1 = df1[df1['value'] == 1]
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df1, columns=['variable'], prefix='', prefix_sep='').sort_values(['Code', 'Price'])
df1.reindex(columns=df.columns, fill_value=0)
```

Edited after I saw how jezrael used `reindex` to both add and drop a column.